# how to remove this error (getting error $localStorage.getItem is not a function)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to save my data on local storage but I am getting error **$localStorage.getItem** is not a function.Actually i am using ionic framework .I need to store data in persistance and get data from persistance .I use ngstorage.js .I also include that module , but getting the undefined error

getting error in this line
       **`return $localStorage.getItem("list");`**
Here is my code
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.stationselect').factory('stationListDownload', stationListDownload);
    stationListDownload.$inject=['$http','$localStorage']
    function stationListDownload($http,$localStorage){
        var list;
        return {
            getDownloadList: function(){
               return $http.get("http://caht.firstrail.com/FGRailApps/jservices/rest/stationList");
            },
            getlist :function(){
               return $localStorage.getItem("list");
            },
            setList :function (list){
                this.list=list;
            }
        }

    }
})();
```

**edit**

```
 var list= stationListDownload.getlist();
    if(list==null ||typeof list=='undefined' ){
        stationListDownload.getDownloadList().then(function(data){
            $scope.loadingIndicator.hide();
            console.log("success")
            $localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(data));
        },function(error){
            console.log("error")
        })
    }else {
        console.log('else condition')
       cosole.log(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are my thought on the above issue

- Think so you have missed out to inject the **'ngStorage'** module.
- Instead of `$localStorage.getItem("list")` you can use `$localStorage.list`.
- Instead of `$localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(data));` you can use `$localStorage.list = data`

Comment: could you please check code https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

Comment: dont use `$localStorage.setItem("list",JSON.stringify(data));` instead use `$localStorage.list = data`

Comment: got it ...!! great answer ...!!

Comment: could you please tell me why this error come $ionicLoading instance.hide() has been deprecated. Use $ionicLoading.hide().

Answer (score 1):

For the ngStorage library, there isn't a `getItem()` method, you simply read and write using standard object member access:

```
getlist :function(){
   return $localStorage.list;
},
setList :function (list){
    $localStorage.list=list;
}
```

Comment: but how to save that list

Comment: As soon as you assign to $localStorage.list, it will be stored in browser local storage. You don't need to do anything - it just works.

Answer (score 0):

The Function getItem is for the HTML5 localStorage. In your Code, you use the AngularJS $localStorage.

So you should use $localStorage.get('list');

For more Information about de AngularJS $localStorage you should read this -> http://ghost.scriptwerx.io/angularjs-localstorage/

**Update**
Only for AngularJS `$localStorage`. The question is for the `ngstorage.js` localStorage.

Comment: he is using `ngstorage.js` not `angular-swx-local-storage.js`